# How to set CSS nth-child in this case?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I'm trying to create react logo with pure css, but in this case nth-child not works to set rotate :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title></title>
<style media="screen">
  body{
    background-color: #20232a;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
  }
  main{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
  }
  .container{
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    background: #fff;
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
  }
  .container .circle{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: #00d8ff;
    border-radius: 50%;
  }
  .container .ellipse{
    width: 480px;
    height: 150px;
    position: absolute;
    border: 20px solid #00d8ff;
    border-radius: 100%;
  }
  .container .ellipse:nth-child(1){
    transform: rotate(120deg);
    background: red;
  }
  .container .ellipse:nth-child(2){
    transform: rotate(-120deg);
    background: green;
  }
  .container .ellipse:nth-child(3){
    background: yellow;
  }
</style>
</head>
<body>

<main>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="circle"></div>
    <div class="ellipse"></div>
    <div class="ellipse"></div>
    <div class="ellipse"></div>
  </div>
</main>

</body>
</html>
```

I've used `.container .ellipse:nth-child(number)` to select ellipse and rotate them, but apparently that selector can't find my target ?!?!

I this case the third ellipse hasn't rotate, but for ellipse one and two must set 120 or -120 degree to set logo style ...

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue is that nth-child is with respect to all other siblings.
So your indexes are off by 1.
You want 2, 3 and 4, not 1, 2, and 3!

The reference for this is: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child

Comment: ok, that works right. but how about `.container .ellipse` ? that doesn't check this selector and makes loop on only `.sllipse` divs ?!

Comment: .container .ellipse is different, this is saying: 'apply this style to elements with class "ellipse" that are children of elements with class "container"'. I hope this makes sense, I may have misunderstood your follow up question.

Answer (score 1):

The `nth-child` property will be set based on the parent's children and not by class-names.

You will have to modify it as second, third and fourth child and it will work.

```css
body {
  background-color: #20232a;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

main {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.container {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  background: #fff;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.container .circle {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #00d8ff;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.container .ellipse {
  width: 480px;
  height: 150px;
  position: absolute;
  border: 20px solid #00d8ff;
  border-radius: 100%;
}

.container .ellipse:nth-child(2) {
  transform: rotate(120deg);
  background: red;
}

.container .ellipse:nth-child(3) {
  transform: rotate(-120deg);
  background: green;
}

.container .ellipse:nth-child(4) {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="circle"></div>
    <div class="ellipse"></div>
    <div class="ellipse"></div>
    <div class="ellipse"></div>
  </div>
</main>
```